# Leetcode matching pairs

Tags: ruby, syntax

The match method takes in a string and the index of opening parentheses. The method needs to return the index of the matching parentheses. If the given index is not to open parentheses, or there are no matching parentheses, return -1. See the examples below.

```
Example:
ParenthesesMatcher.match("(())", 1) => 2
The given index is for the second parentheses. 
The matching is the closing parentheses at index 2.

ParenthesesMatcher.match("(())", 0) => 3
The given index is for the first parentheses. 
The matching is the last closing parentheses at index 3.

ParenthesesMatcher.match("asdf", 0) => -1
The given index is not an opening parentheses. Return -1.

ParenthesesMatcher.match("(()", 0) => -1
The given index does not have a matching parentheses. Return -1.
```

Coherent solution #1: Short, one-method, simple.

```
def match(string, start)
  return -1 unless str[start] == ?(
    open = 0
    str[start..-1].each_char.with_index do |c, i|
      if c == ?(
        open += 1
      elsif c == ?)
        open -= 1
        return start + i if open == 0
      end
    end

    -1
  end

end
```

Comment: What's the problem id?

Comment: It's not on Leetcode, had an acquaintance send it to me because they were given it today. He said I should try it because he couldn't figure it out during his interview and he couldn't find any similar problems on Leetcode. I'm at a loss here too.

Comment: Basically, -1 means something unexpected happens, and the method caller should check it not equals -1. And some language don't take -1 as a valid index. And I think a stack probably could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tagged as a Ruby question, so I thought I'd post a Ruby answer. I really liked @lincr's stack-based method above, but I've simplified it a little. It analyses the input string to produce an array of the start and end offsets of each pair of paretheses. Then it just iterates over the list looking for a matching start point.

```rb
def paren_pairs(sample)
  pairs = []
  stack = []
  sample.chars.each_with_index do |chr, i|
    stack.push i if chr == '('
    pairs.append [stack.pop, i] if chr == ')'
  end
  pairs
end

def match_parens(sample, i)
  paren_pairs(sample).reduce(-1) { |result, pair| pair[0] == i ? pair[1] : result }
end
```

So:

```rb
tests = [['(())', 1, 2],
         ['(())', 0, 3],
         ['asdf', 0, -1],
         ['(()', 0, -1]]

tests.each do |test|
  sample, index, expected = test
  puts "#{sample}, #{index}, expected #{expected}, got #{match_parens sample, index}"
end
```

Results:

```
(()), 1, expected 2, got 2
(()), 0, expected 3, got 3
asdf, 0, expected -1, got -1
((), 0, expected -1, got -1
```

Comment: Perfect. This is "sort of" where I was trying to go with my method, but I've never even used stack before so I was trying to do a inc/dec process to match them.

Comment: It's just an array, but it's being used as a stack in this instance. Think of those spring-loaded plate dispensers you see in cafeterias. Ruby arrays have a number of aliased methods that do the same thing, so I used ```push``` and ```pop``` because they describe the stack behaviour we want.

Answer (score 1):

I write a small python program to demonstrate the idea using stack here. You save the indices of '(' seen in the stack, and when you see a ')' comes, you pop a '(' from the stack.

```py
def match_parentheses(s, index):
    stack = []
    marker = -1
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i != index:
            if s[i] == '(':
                stack.append(i)
            elif s[i] == ')':

                # in our processed ()s, there are more ')' than '(',
                # just ignore it, the stack is guaranted to be empty 
                if len(stack) == 0:
                    continue
                peek = stack[-1]
                if marker >= 0 and peek == marker:
                    return i
                else:
                    stack.pop()
        else:
            if s[i] == ')':
                return stack[-1] if len(stack) > 0 else -1
            elif s[i] == '(':
                marker = i
                stack.append(i)
            else:
                return -1
    return -1
match_parentheses("(())", 1)
match_parentheses("(())", 0)
match_parentheses("abcd", 0)
match_parentheses("(()", 0)
match_parentheses("())", 2)
match_parentheses("(())()()", 7)
```

Ouput:

```
2 3 -1 -1 -1 6
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, trying to understand. I'm seeing strings being handled as arrays, not key/value pairs.

What I'd do, and this is fairly naive, I know, is first check to make sure the index is for an open paren, then increment and decrement a number as you run through the string/array, starting at the given index, so that you reach 0 when you find the matching parent. Like, for "((((())))" and you want to find the match for index 1, you have a variable called `inc` that has an initial value of 0. At index 1, it increments to 1, at index 2 to 2, at 3 to 3, at 4 to 4, at 5 it decrements to 3, at 6 to 2, at 7 to 1, and at 8 to 0, so that 8 is the match for 1.

My head's too full of Java right now to come up with coherent Ruby code, I'd wind up throwing in a bunch of random semicolons.

But it feels like that isn't the whole problem. Is there more explaining it?

The word, by the way, is syntactically, not syntaxically.

Comment: This is actuallly pretty good for me to work with. I'll try this out and yolo into it I guess. (This is probably the 30th Leetcode problem I've done ever so I'm not exactly an expert at what I'm doing lol) Pretty much all the leetcode problems I've done so far included K/V arrays so that's the closest I have to this as far as familiarity goes. If it's a string, then I should probably implement a split function for it to separate them into individual and sequential values to iterate through? The rest of the explanation is just test it via rspec.

Comment: You can handle strings as arrays in Ruby, iirc.